# Convert SQL query set into Django Model Query-set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I need a little help, I come from working with relational data models and now I venture into Django Framework, I need to make an API that returns something like this SQL query

```
SELECT user_profile_userprofile.email,
     user_profile_userprofile.name,
     business_unity.active AS status,
     profile.name AS profile,
     business_unity.name AS unit

FROM user_profile_userprofile
      JOIN profile ON user_profile_userprofile.id = profile.id
      JOIN user_profile_unity ON user_profile_unity.user_id = user_profile_userprofile.id
      JOIN business_unity ON user_profile_unity.id = business_unity.id;
```

The models are already created but I don't know how to make a view in python that meets the conditions of this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to "preload" the associations using [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related), and then you just use the normal methods to navigate them.

Assuming your models are something like

```py
class UserProfile(Model):
    profile = ForeignKey("Profiles", ...)
    unity = ForeignKey("Unity", ...)

class Unity(Model):
    business_unity = ForeignKey("business.Unity", ...)
```

```
qs = UserProfile.select_related("profile", "unity__business_unity").all()
up = qs[0]
```

Now you have all your data loaded (and more)

```py
print(up.email)
print(up.name)
print(up.unity.business_unity.active)
print(up.profile.name)
print(up.unity.business_unity.name)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: gracias Con tu ayuda pude resolver

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is correct you should mark it as such.